# How to prevent the debugger from calling some source code when paused?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

In visual studio, when an application is stopped during debug mode you can hover over an object/property to see whats inside of it.

[image]

When you open up an object using the debugger like I did with the above picture, the property has it's Get method called as a way for the debugger to retrieve the value of the property to show the user.

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        foo.MyLock.EnterWriteLock();
        foo.Bar = 5.1;
        foo.MyLock.ExitWriteLock();

        // "I stop here and attempt to see what the value of Bar is via the debugger."
        foo.MyLock.EnterReadLock();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
        foo.MyLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    private double bar;
    public double Bar 
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyLock.IsReadLockHeld);
            Debug.Assert(MyLock.IsReadLockHeld, "Please enter the read lock before attempting to read this property.");
            return bar;
        }
        set
        {
            Debug.Assert(MyLock.IsWriteLockHeld, "Please enter the write lock before attempting to write this property.");
            bar = value;
        }
    }

    public ReaderWriterLockSlim MyLock { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        MyLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    }
}
```

In my application I add in a Debug.Assert() call into my Get accessors to make sure that Foo in this example has been locked. Whenever my code called Bar, foo should be locked as per design, however when the debugger attempts to view bar, foo won't be locked which means the assert should fail.

When the debugger encounters an assert that fails it will sometimes suppress the assert popup and other times it will show the assert pop-up as per normal failed assert behavior. As best as I can tell the Assert popup appears to be suppressed for the first 1-2 times the debugger views the value of Bar but every time after those first 1-2 the popup is allowed to show. While this is the most common behavior of the assert suppressing this is not always the case because on other runs of the application the debugger never stopped suppressing no matter how many times the debugger viewed Bar.

**Question:** For my application the desired behavior would be for the asserts to be suppressed 100% of the time. How do I achieve this?

**Edit:**
Also, if it helps when the debugger hits one of the asserts and it fails the below message it written to the Debug output. This is the exact same message regardless of whether or not the assert is suppressed.

```
---- DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED ----
---- Assert Short Message ----
Please enter the read lock before attempting to read this property.
---- Assert Long Message ----

   at TestApp_Debugging.Foo.get_Bar() in c:\Users\Adrian.vanBerkhout\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp_Debugging\TestApp_Debugging\Program.cs:line 37
   at TestApp_Debugging.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Adrian.vanBerkhout\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp_Debugging\TestApp_Debugging\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) may help... or disable property evaluation in VS... (personally I think you get what you deserve when putting Assert in property getter :) )

Comment: I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov - code that does anything more complicated than simple arithmetic should be a method rather than a property.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov even when using the DebuggerDisplay `[DebuggerDisplay("myBar = {bar}")]` on the Bar property the assert is still being called. When I'm debugging it does display the DebuggerDisplay message. Do you have any ideas why it might be still calling the property?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Do you agree with Aasmund that I should replace all of my properties with methods? That would certainly solve the assert issue, but it seems a shame to lose the functionality of properties.

Comment: @Adrian773 trying to enforce thread safety with asserts/exceptions is hard (you can check how many threads are around about "cross thread access to UI element" for example). I'd try to rework API to avoid *exposing* locks altogether - i.e. check ConcurrentQueue as an example. Yes, it does mean no properties, but you may be able design interface that is really hard to use wrong (unlike current one where you need 3 methods/properties to be precisely ordered to get successful result.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In my actual application it is a bit cleaner and works like `using(foo.AcquireReaderLock()) {  DoSomething(foo.Bar) }` without the lock itself being actually exposed. I like the idea of a locking mechanism that is completely internal, but what about when the user wants to do some sort of non-atomic action such as `if (foo.GetBar() > 10) { foo.SetBar(0); }`. If the locking mechanisms are all hidden inside of foo then this creates a race condition.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Oh and could you please elaborate on "(you can check how many threads are around about "cross thread access to UI element" for example)" I don't quite understand what you are meaning.

Comment: @Adrian773 https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+winfrorm+cross+thread - WinForms/WPF enforces threading access with exception but since natural way of writing code (before async/await) ends up with running code on wrong thread every single person at least once runs into that exception. If you can - design your API so when used normally in most obvious way it is hard to get code wrong.

Comment: @Adrian773 on `foo.AcquireReaderLock()` - it is way easier to never release the lock than you seem to think... What about how one will write code that needs confirmation button click - get the lock, let user click on button, finish operation, release the lock - if anything fails in between object locked forever...

Comment: Maybe the example is simplified, but why not use [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sh52ebc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods in the property implementation itself?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution [here](https://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2009/08/18/debugger-property-evaluation-side-effects/). Decorate your problem properties with the [DebuggerBrowsable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
```

Ideally you'd never need to do this. However, we have some properties that trigger a code contract exception when evaluated (in debug), which causes Visual Studio to get very confused. You probably need to decorate both the property on the class and any interface it implements.